# Tabulate data and find max value c#

Tags: c#, sorting, max

I want to create a table of values where for every "t" value, function "TabRot" calculates a result, and find the value of "t" at which "TabRot" is maximum. Since my stepping interval is 0.001 in the following code (can be 0.00001) too; what would be the fastest way to compute this  ?

The catch is there can be two/ more same max values, I just need to pick the first one.

code so far:

```
// Devise optimize function
for (double t = -0.025; t <= 0.025; t = t + 0.001)//theta[{t, -.05, .05, .001}]
                    {
                        //Table[t,TabRot]
                        DataTable TabVal = new DataTable();
                        TabVal.Rows.Add(RotTab.TabRot(t, i1));

                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not clear with your question but You will need to instantiate the datatable outside loop else you are creating a datatable in every loop iteration

```
DataTable TabVal = new DataTable();
for (double t = -0.025; t <= 0.025; t = t + 0.001)//theta[{t, -.05, .05, .001}]
                    {
                        TabVal.Rows.Add(RotTab.TabRot(t, i1));
                    }
```

Per your comment, looks like you are trying to store a single scalar value. In such case it's much efficient to use a `list<double>` like

```
    List<double> TabVal = new List<double>();
    for (double t = -0.025; t <= 0.025; t = t + 0.001)//theta[{t, -.05, .05, .001}]
   {
      TabVal.Add(RotTab.TabRot(t, i1));
   }
```

Once you have the list filled you can find the max value by calling the `MAX()` method like

```
TabVal.Max();
```

Comment: would it be wise to use a faster computation collection type instead of table ?? Since the stepping order is 0.001, it can be as small as 0.0001 and then I have to iterate through the table to find at what "t" I get max result.

Comment: Well, in that case why you need to use a datatable, why not just use a `list<float>` or `list<double>`. See edit in answer.

Comment: exactly, I was thinking about List<track> but got stuck as to how would I iterate through the list to find the max val  and the associated "t" value.

Comment: @abhilashsukumari, see edit in answer if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that RotTab.TabRot(double, object); returns a double.
Your comment indicates to me that you want tabVal to hold (t,TabRot(t,i1)), so that's what this'll fill it with.

```
//Defined elsewhere: i1, RotTab[.TabRot]
//populates tabVal with (t,trot) pairs
//maxt contains the t value that produced the maximum 
DataTable tabVal = new DataTable();//move this here, otherwise tabVal will only ever have the last item in it
//initialize what your columns are
tabVal.Columns.Add("t", double);
tabVal.Columns.Add("trot", double);

//These should probably be somewhere else, but for this code I'm putting them here. Magic numbers are bad, mmkay?
double start = -0.025;
double end = 0.025;
double step = 0.001;

//init to the first value, since that's definitely a valid possible max
double max = RotTab.TabRot(start, i1);
double maxt = start;

//used for holding what we're looking at.
double cur;
for (double t = start; t <= end; t += step) {
    cur = RotTab.TabRot(t, i1);
    if (cur > max) {
        max = cur;
        maxt = t;
    }
    tabVal.Rows.Add(new double[] {t, cur});
}
```

If all you're gonna do is take the max and occasionally look up a t->trot (without wanting to calc trot again), you could use a Dictionary instead.
Would probably be more efficient.

EDIT: If all you needed was the max, bruh...

```
//These should probably be somewhere else, but for this code I'm putting them here. Magic numbers are bad, mmkay?
double start = -0.025;
double end = 0.025;
double step = 0.001;

double max = RotTab.TabRot(start, i1);
double maxt = start;
double cur;
for (int t = start; t <= end; t += step) {
    cur = RotTab.TabRot(t, i1);
    if (cur > max) {
        max = cur;
        maxt = t;
    }
}
```

You don't need to store anything at that point, just find the max as you go.

Comment: Would also like to note, since you edited OP.... This will pick the first one. To pick the last instead, change
    cur > max
to
    cur >= max